# @Synchronized is not working as expected in KMM

Tags: android, kotlin, kmm

I have a `Ktor` class where I need to do action on unauthorized exception(when token is expired), for this action I need to have `synchronized` action, otherwise it is not working correctly, the problem is that `@Synchronized` is not synchronize the action and is not waiting for action to finish for next one.

```
       fun ktorFunction(){

        HttpResponseValidator {
        handleResponseException { exception ->
            kermit.e { "In ${exception.message}" }

            val clientException =
                exception as? ClientRequestException ?: return@handleResponseException
            val exceptionResponse = clientException.response

            when (exceptionResponse.status) {
                HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized -> {
                    test(){
                        kermit.v { "Error message" }
                    }
            }
         }
      }
   }




@Synchronized
fun test(messageTest: () -> Unit) {
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
    delay(3000)
    messageTest()

    }
}
```

The idea is I want `test` function to not be called from other thread until it is finished, whatever the action is in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`launch` is a function that starts a coroutine asynchronously and immediately returns, so this is behaving as it should. If you want to synchronize coroutines, you should use [Mutex](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.sync/-mutex/).

I'll leave it alone in the example before, but IMO, it's a code smell to create a CoroutineScope if you're not going to manage its lifecycle.

```
private val testMutex = Mutex()

fun test(messageTest: () -> Unit) {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
        testMutex.withLock {
            delay(3000)
            messageTest()
        }
    }
}
```